# How can I correct/delete iOS holidays on iDevice

Tags: ios, ical

I discovered a number of strange entries in iCal on my iDevices which I didn't enter, and also were just on this device and neither my Mac nor the other device.

After a little search I found that my iPhone has a calendar for German holidays and the iPad a calendar for Swiss holidays. This is rather strange as I live in Austria and haven't visited these countries since the time I got these devices (>2 years). These calendars are in the section where also birthdays are and can not be edited or deleted. They also don't show up on iCal on the mac. I also checked the timezone on the devices - but this is set to Vienna - Austria.

So how would I fix them to Austrian holidays? - or at least delete so I won't be irritated by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot delete the Holiday Calender on your iOS device. However, you can hide it via Calender app. In the Calendar app, tap Calendars in the bottom center and uncheck the Holiday calendar. And, here's how you can add Austrian holidays to your iPhone and iPad calender:

1. Go to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars
2. Now, tap on Add Account
3. Scroll down and tap on Other
4. Tap on “Add Subscribed Calendar”
5. Type in “http://laudatio.com/florian/ical/AustrianHolidays.ics” and press **“Next”**, and then press “**Save”**
6. Press **"Done"**. Congrats, you've added Austrian Holidays to your calendar.

You might find this useful: http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-add-us-holidays-to-iphone-calendar/ Hope it helps!

FYI: My iPhone has a calender for Indian holidays.

Comment: Well guess that's how it is. But I think it strange that they messed up such a simple feature. Will drop apple support a note - but they don't make it easy :)

Answer (score 0):

it very Easy to add, Remove or update US holidays or other country holidays in your iDevice.

1. Go to The Setting > Mail, Contacts, Calendars
2. New account, Select Other option
3. Add Subscribed Calendar.
4. Enter .iCs path in Text. if you want to update for your country, download .ics file from below given link.

http://www.icalworld.com/holidays.html

for Brief introduction check out below given links on Add, Remove or Update your calenders holidays list,

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete US Holidays from the "Other" section of the Calendar app. But if the calendar shows up in the "Subscribed" section, you can delete it as follows:

1. Open Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Subscribed Calendars
2. Tap the calendar you want to delete.
3. Tap "Delete Account" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - Setting --> General --> Language & Region --> 'Change current Region Country to the holiday country you want'. iPhone will update and after sometime, your calendars will show new region set holiday calendar. If that doesn't help after change, force close calendar after region change n check again. 
Eg. If ur calendar is showing US holiday's, and u want UK holidays, your region in 'language & region' should be set to 'United Kingdom'